# Add new ChildNodes to many parent elements

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a planets.xml file with 3,146 planets and many childnodes for each planet.  I have been reading tutorials and testing it out since last week trying to get this to work but, I am not getting it.  I simply need to know how to add a new childnode "axis" into each parent "planet" element under the "ycoord" node.  And then I should be able to duplicate that for all the other elements that some planets do not have filled out (orbit, pressure, percentWater, etc).

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<planets>
    <planet>
        <name>A Place</name>
        <xcood>-123.764</xcood>
        <ycood>272.182</ycood>
    </planet>
    <planet>
        <name>Abadan</name>
        <xcood>-70.319</xcood>
        <ycood>-95.949</ycood>
        <pressure>3</pressure>
        <gravity>1.03</gravity>
        <lifeForm>7</lifeForm>
        <climate>2</climate>
        <percentWater>63</percentWater>
        <temperature>22</temperature>
        <spectralClass>F</spectralClass>
        <subtype>1</subtype>
        <luminosity>V</luminosity>
        <sysPos>5</sysPos>
        <socioIndustrial>C-C-D-C-C</socioIndustrial>
        <landMass>Abadan Major (Abbasid)</landMass>
        <landMass>Abadan Minor</landMass>
        <landMass>Kuran Major</landMass>
        <landMass>Kuran Minor</landMass>
        <hpg>B</hpg>
    </planet>
    <planet>
        <name>Abagnar</name>
        <xcood>380.231</xcood>
        <ycood>314.823</ycood>
        <faction>UND</faction>
        <factionChange>
            <date>2750-01-01</date>
            <faction>DC</faction>
        </factionChange>
    </planet>
</planets>
```

Very short snip from the planets.xml

And my code which is only adding the new  tag on the very last planet of the list.

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click

    Dim xmlPlanets As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    xmlPlanets.Load(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Planets\planets.xml")
    Dim nodePlanets As XmlNodeList = xmlPlanets.GetElementsByTagName("planet")

    Dim axis As XmlElement = xmlPlanets.CreateElement("axis")
    axis.InnerText = getAxis()

    For Each node As XmlNode In nodePlanets

        If node.ChildNodes.Equals(axis) Then

        Else

            node.InsertAfter(axis, node.FirstChild)

        End If

    Next

    Dim orbit As XmlElement = xmlPlanets.CreateElement("orbit")
    orbit.InnerText = getOrbit()

    xmlPlanets.Save("planets.xml")

    Dim pressure As XmlElement = xmlPlanets.CreateElement("pressure")
    Dim gravity As XmlElement = xmlPlanets.CreateElement("gravity")
    Dim percentWater As XmlElement = xmlPlanets.CreateElement("percentWater")
    Dim temperature As XmlElement = xmlPlanets.CreateElement("temperature")
    Dim satellite As XmlElement = xmlPlanets.CreateElement("satellite")

    Dim writer As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter("planets.xml", Nothing)
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    xmlPlanets.WriteContentTo(writer)
    writer.Flush()
    writer.Close()

    'Dim readPressure As String = nodePlanets.Item(cbPlanets.SelectedIndex).Item("pressure").InnerText
    'txtAtmosphere.Text = getPressure(readPressure)

End Sub
```

This is just for a personal scenario generator project with megamek/mekHQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a class from the xml. Before you do that, take a sample of the xml, as you have above, and add the axis node to any one of the planet nodes. Then in visual studio, Edit >> Paste Xml as Classes. It will create your model.

Xml:

```xml
<planets>
  <planet>
    <name>A Place</name>
    <xcood>-123.764</xcood>
    <ycood>272.182</ycood>
  </planet>
  <planet>
    <name>Abadan</name>
    <xcood>-70.319</xcood>
    <ycood>-95.949</ycood>
    <axis>some string</axis> <!--added this-->
    <pressure>3</pressure>
    <gravity>1.03</gravity>
    <lifeForm>7</lifeForm>
    <climate>2</climate>
    <percentWater>63</percentWater>
    <temperature>22</temperature>
    <spectralClass>F</spectralClass>
    <subtype>1</subtype>
    <luminosity>V</luminosity>
    <sysPos>5</sysPos>
    <socioIndustrial>C-C-D-C-C</socioIndustrial>
    <landMass>Abadan Major (Abbasid)</landMass>
    <landMass>Abadan Minor</landMass>
    <landMass>Kuran Major</landMass>
    <landMass>Kuran Minor</landMass>
    <hpg>B</hpg>
  </planet>
  <planet>
    <name>Abagnar</name>
    <xcood>380.231</xcood>
    <ycood>314.823</ycood>
    <faction>UND</faction>
    <factionChange>
      <date>2750-01-01</date>
      <faction>DC</faction>
    </factionChange>
  </planet>
</planets>
```

Generated class:

```vb
'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True),
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=False)>
Partial Public Class planets

    Private planetField() As planetsPlanet

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("planet")>
    Public Property planet() As planetsPlanet()
        Get
            Return Me.planetField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.planetField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)>
Partial Public Class planetsPlanet

    Private nameField As String

    Private xcoodField As Decimal

    Private ycoodField As Decimal

    Private factionField As String

    Private factionChangeField As planetsPlanetFactionChange

    Private axisField As String

    Private pressureField As Byte

    Private pressureFieldSpecified As Boolean

    Private gravityField As Decimal

    Private gravityFieldSpecified As Boolean

    Private lifeFormField As Byte

    Private lifeFormFieldSpecified As Boolean

    Private climateField As Byte

    Private climateFieldSpecified As Boolean

    Private percentWaterField As Byte

    Private percentWaterFieldSpecified As Boolean

    Private temperatureField As Byte

    Private temperatureFieldSpecified As Boolean

    Private spectralClassField As String

    Private subtypeField As Byte

    Private subtypeFieldSpecified As Boolean

    Private luminosityField As String

    Private sysPosField As Byte

    Private sysPosFieldSpecified As Boolean

    Private socioIndustrialField As String

    Private landMassField() As String

    Private hpgField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return Me.nameField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.nameField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property xcood() As Decimal
        Get
            Return Me.xcoodField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.xcoodField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property ycood() As Decimal
        Get
            Return Me.ycoodField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.ycoodField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property faction() As String
        Get
            Return Me.factionField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.factionField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property factionChange() As planetsPlanetFactionChange
        Get
            Return Me.factionChangeField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.factionChangeField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property axis() As String
        Get
            Return Me.axisField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.axisField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property pressure() As Byte
        Get
            Return Me.pressureField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.pressureField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Property pressureSpecified() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.pressureFieldSpecified
        End Get
        Set
            Me.pressureFieldSpecified = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property gravity() As Decimal
        Get
            Return Me.gravityField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.gravityField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Property gravitySpecified() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.gravityFieldSpecified
        End Get
        Set
            Me.gravityFieldSpecified = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property lifeForm() As Byte
        Get
            Return Me.lifeFormField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.lifeFormField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Property lifeFormSpecified() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.lifeFormFieldSpecified
        End Get
        Set
            Me.lifeFormFieldSpecified = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property climate() As Byte
        Get
            Return Me.climateField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.climateField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Property climateSpecified() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.climateFieldSpecified
        End Get
        Set
            Me.climateFieldSpecified = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property percentWater() As Byte
        Get
            Return Me.percentWaterField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.percentWaterField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Property percentWaterSpecified() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.percentWaterFieldSpecified
        End Get
        Set
            Me.percentWaterFieldSpecified = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property temperature() As Byte
        Get
            Return Me.temperatureField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.temperatureField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Property temperatureSpecified() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.temperatureFieldSpecified
        End Get
        Set
            Me.temperatureFieldSpecified = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property spectralClass() As String
        Get
            Return Me.spectralClassField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.spectralClassField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property subtype() As Byte
        Get
            Return Me.subtypeField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.subtypeField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Property subtypeSpecified() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.subtypeFieldSpecified
        End Get
        Set
            Me.subtypeFieldSpecified = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property luminosity() As String
        Get
            Return Me.luminosityField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.luminosityField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property sysPos() As Byte
        Get
            Return Me.sysPosField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.sysPosField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Property sysPosSpecified() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.sysPosFieldSpecified
        End Get
        Set
            Me.sysPosFieldSpecified = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property socioIndustrial() As String
        Get
            Return Me.socioIndustrialField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.socioIndustrialField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("landMass")>
    Public Property landMass() As String()
        Get
            Return Me.landMassField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.landMassField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property hpg() As String
        Get
            Return Me.hpgField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.hpgField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)>
Partial Public Class planetsPlanetFactionChange

    Private dateField As Date

    Private factionField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType:="date")>
    Public Property [date]() As Date
        Get
            Return Me.dateField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.dateField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property faction() As String
        Get
            Return Me.factionField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.factionField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Now, this class is very easy to work with because you have .NET classes instead of trying to navigate an xml file. I suggest using xml serialization to load the xml into the .NET object:

```vb
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s As New XmlSerializer(GetType(planets))
        Dim p As planets
        ' load the xml file
        Using fs As New FileStream("planets.xml", FileMode.Open)
            p = s.Deserialize(fs)
        End Using
        ' operations on the planet objects
        For Each planet In p.planet
            planet.axis = "new value"
        Next
        ' overwrite the xml file
        Using fs As New FileStream("planets.xml", FileMode.Truncate)
            s.Serialize(fs, p)
        End Using
    End Sub

End Module
```

As you see, this code will set each planet's axis to "new value". Of course you can set it to whatever you want because in the for each loop you have access to all the other *properties* of the planet. Not thinking of them as xml nodes makes them much easier to work with.

Note: Visual Studio's Paste XML as Classes is great, but if you have strings which should really be limited to a few values, it's a good idea to make them Enums (which the generator can't possibly know without your intervention). You should modify the generated classes or model to make it more accurately represent your data.

Comment: Ah ha, thats what I needed.  All the examples and tutorials on the web are just for a xml with only a single parent (planet in my case) and was having a mental block on how to get this to work for 3000 planets in an automated way.

Comment: Ok I am using visual studio 2017 framework 4.7.#### and I am not getting a Edit>paste special after copying my xml text, cursor outside of the classes I already have and tried in a new module>code file.  I wonder if they changed something.

Comment: That's the version I used when I did it.

Comment: Googled it and made sure my target framework was over 4.5 (was .NET 4.6.1) and googled some more and found out I did not have WCF installed(didn't know what that was)....Im learning.  It works now that paste as classes is neat.

Comment: Ok, it pasted the xml as classes in a completely different way/format for planetsPlanet compared to your example code.  It created an itemsField as Object, itemsElementName as Enum and textField as string.  With a whole `<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("axis", GetType(String)),` table and then properties with a get and set for each of the three variables.  But, I cant figure out how to set the value of axis with it like that so, will rewrite what it did off your example.

Comment: Can't you use the classes I pasted in my answer?

Comment: Fixed the xml class so that it is just like your example (without the specified properties).  Created a objPlanets class with your serialize code and it errors on me: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (19, 4).'` Line 19 position 4 is between the indented space of the subtype line, makes no sense.
`  <subtype>1</subtype>`
[link](https://imgur.com/rw9XR3j)VS IDE
[link](https://imgur.com/nmgyesc) planets.xml

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using xml linq which makes task very simple

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim planets As List(Of XElement) = doc.Descendants("planet").ToList()

        For Each planet In planets
            planet.Add(New XElement("axis", 123))
        Next planet

    End Sub

End Module
```