# need help creating xml attribute with special character data

Tags: xml, vb.net

So I have an app in VB.net (VS2017 if that matters) that generates an xml document to feed data into another application. The xml document that must be used requires the following line after certain sections:

```
<format position="11" type="text" text="&#13;&#10;"/>
```

So when I append the text attribute, I would like to do it something like this:

```
element.SetAttribute("text","&#13;&#10;")
```

to return the data that I need. But the &s of course keep throwing amp;s into the mix. I tried using `&amp;` in lieu of just the &, but that just generates a double amp;amp; everywhere.

I tried using CData but then it includes the CData tag and does not provide the exact attribute that I need to append.

How do I get `&#13;&#10;` to show up as the attribute value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered one of these [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46649927/832052), but you have a specific issue. If you use xml serialization for the writing and reading, it is a non-issue.

Generate a class based on the xml. You can copy a sample of the xml and do Edit >> Paste xml as classes in visual studio. Based on your limited example,

```vb
Partial Public Class format

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()>
    Public Property position() As Byte

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()>
    Public Property type() As String

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()>
    Public Property text() As String

End Class
```

You now have a class you can use to hold information, instead of thinking xml-centric. You can serialize and deserialize the class to and from the file:

```vb
Sub Main()
    Dim x As New format() With ' format object to write to xml
    {
        .position = 11,
        .type = "text",
        .text = "&#13;&#10;"
    }
    Dim s As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(format))
    Using f As New IO.FileStream("format.xml", IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
        s.Serialize(f, x)
    End Using
    Dim y As format ' format object to read from xml
    Using f As New IO.FileStream("format.xml", IO.FileMode.Open)
        y = s.Deserialize(f)
    End Using
    Console.WriteLine(y.text) ' value of y.text = "&#13;&#10;"
End Sub
```

And there is nothing wrong with `&amp`; it is how an `&` is represented in xml. It will be written and read properly with a serializer.

The program outputs the correct value, though this is the xml in the file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<format xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        position="11" type="text" text="&amp;#13;&amp;#10;" />
```

Comment: I know `&amp;` is expected, the problem I have is that the specs I am trying to recreate insist on omitting the amp;. When the xml file is input into the user's system with the attribute value set to `text="&amp;#13;&amp;#10;"`, it's not rendering as a cr lf because of the amp;s.